# Windows detects my camera but won't display it in explorer

Tags: windows-8, usb, windows-explorer, device-manager, windows-8.1-preview

[image: wut]

When I connect my 5DmkII to my computer windows displays the autplay prompt and asks me what I want to do. But it doesn't open the folder when I click that option and instead does nothing.

Looking at the system root it is not displayed as it in the past has been as a usb device. If I check the device manager it is listed, but I have no means of opening it as a folder. Whatever I do, I'm unable to make the device appear in windows explorer

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Open `Disk Management` with <kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and click on `Disk Management`. Here select your camera and assign a dive letter like `F:\`.